# How can I change the filename in a fine-uploader blob request

Tags: blob, filenames, fine-uploader

Using the basic fine-uploader and addFile to insert a blob based entry.Everything goes ok until the server reject the request due to "security issues".
If I convert the blob to a file and send it to the fine-uploader the server is quite happy. The only difference between the two requests is the filename in the request header.

The file-uploader setName() doesn't appear to change to "blob" name.

fails:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Any way to replace the 'filename="blob"' with a name that contains the correct extension - blob.jpg, blob.gif,etc?

```
 var myblob = new Blob([outputBuffer], {type: "image/jpeg"});
     myblob.name = ofile;
     var myfile = new File([myblob], 'ImageTest.jpg', {
             lastModified: new Date(0), // optional - default = now
             type: "image/jpeg" // optional - default = ''
     });
     fineUploader.addFiles({blob:myblob, name:ofile});
     console.log(fineUploader.getName(0));
     fineUploader.setName(0,ofile);
     console.log(fineUploader.getName(0));
     fineUploader.addFiles(myfile);
```

Comment: ["When chunking and multipart encoded are both enabled, why must I determine the original file's name by parsing the qqfilename parameter?](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/faq.html)